# WHERE statement, reading a delimited field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query that is returning my `categories` column in a comma delimited format.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        l.LID, 
        Company, 
        Doors, 
        City, 
        Region, 
        Country, 
        Categories = STUFF((
            SELECT 
                CONVERT(varchar(100), Junc_CatID) + ', '
            FROM BND_ListingJunction_testing j
            WHERE j.Junc_LID = l.LID
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
    FROM BND_Listing_testing l
    GROUP BY
        LID, Company, Doors, City, Region, Country
) x 
WHERE
    x.Categories = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),2)
```

How can I have my where statement look at my `categories` column and determine if it should display on not. Meaning not considering whats in my `categories` column as 1 long string but as individual entities.

If my data set is:

```
LID  Company  Doors   City  Region  Country Categories
1    a        a       a     AL      US      1,6,8,
2    b        b       b     AZ      US      2,6,
3    c        c       c     IA      US      8,40,28,30,
```

and my `WHERE` clause is looking at Category `8` then my results would be

```
LID  Company  Doors   City  Region  Country Categories
1    a        a       a     AL      US      1,6,8,
3    c        c       c     IA      US      8,40,28,30,
```

If it was `6` then my results would be

```
LID  Company  Doors   City  Region  Country Categories
1    a        a       a     AL      US      1,6,8,
2    b        b       b     AZ      US      2,6,
```

etc...

Comment: Why not do the filtering before the concatenation?

Comment: My problem is if I filter prior concatenation the GRID on my website i'm using this query in will show any LID duplicated X amount of times it's been categorized in my Junction table. Which results in showing company X 10 times if it's been categorized 10 times. I want to show it just once yet be able to filter via the where statement .

Comment: Never never **NEVER** store csv data in a column.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn i'm not storing csv data, i'm pulling data from a junction table and displaying it via XML from the select statement

Comment: Do you're compare before doing the STUFF()

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn could you give me a small example? I'm not sure how to go about that. Would the compare look at the entire string or each delimited value as an individual entity?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn "never" is such a strong term... I'm fine with it when used to optimize reads (to avoid having to do a 1-many lookup), but not as part of a filter. We use something very similar to store tags on questions - but it isn't used except to make fetch cheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comparison, you are checking for exact equality, which you'll probably never get.

```
x.Categories = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),2)

-- becomes this when evaluated
x.Categories = '2'
```

Instead, you want something that is like your category, or something like this

```
x.Categories LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), 2) + ',%'
```

combined with Tony's extra comma in front of your category list. The extra commas are to prevent `'6,'` from matching `'2,26,86,'`

Comment: thank you for this recommendation it make it work! Now i just need to figure out how to add my additional "Filters" for city, state & country. Thanks again.

Comment: @AlexP -- if you care about performance you'd be better served with my answer.

Comment: @Hogan I will try you answer again when I initially tried it probably I was missing something. I'll revisit it right now my next big task is cleaning 10k records in excel 1by1 for correct info :|

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to post part of your query.  The WHERE clause that you need would be added to the part you forgot.

In that WHERE clause you will determine whether the row should show up by checking a subquery on the categories table, like this (look at the bottom 2 lines):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        l.LID, 
        Company, 
        Doors, 
        City, 
        Region, 
        Country, 
        Categories = STUFF((
            SELECT 
                CONVERT(varchar(100), Junc_CatID) + ', '
            FROM BND_ListingJunction_testing j
            WHERE j.Junc_LID = l.LID
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
            FROM BND_Listing_testing l
            GROUP BY LID, Company, Doors, City, Region, Country
        FROM WhateverThisTableIsCalled l
        WHERE LID IN (SELECT LID from BND_ListingJunction_testing WHERE Junc_CATID = @TheIdOfInterest)
) x
```

Answer (score 2):

Just join back to the table to test for existence

This will find all with 6.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        l.LID, 
        Company, 
        Doors, 
        City, 
        Region, 
        Country, 
        Categories = STUFF((
            SELECT 
                CONVERT(varchar(100), Junc_CatID) + ', '
            FROM BND_ListingJunction_testing j
            WHERE j.Junc_LID = l.LID
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
    FROM BND_Listing_testing l
    GROUP BY
        LID, Company, Doors, City, Region, Country
) x
JOIN BND_ListingJunction_testing j ON (j.Junc_LID, Junc_CatID) = (x.LID, 6)
```

or if it easier to understand

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        l.LID, 
        Company, 
        Doors, 
        City, 
        Region, 
        Country, 
        Categories = STUFF((
            SELECT 
                CONVERT(varchar(100), Junc_CatID) + ', '
            FROM BND_ListingJunction_testing j
            WHERE j.Junc_LID = l.LID
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
    FROM BND_Listing_testing l
    GROUP BY
        LID, Company, Doors, City, Region, Country
) X
WHERE EXISTS
   (SELECT 1 FROM BND_ListingJunction_testing j
    WHERE j.Junc_LID = x.LID and Junc_CatID = 6)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'll dissect this better to see if I can get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Add ',' before your categories like ',1,2,6,8,' and then you can easy to use

```
where ',' + categories like '%,6,%'
```

Comment: If my categories column contains a string like `,1,2,6,8,` and in my where I pass `,2,` will it display that row? I've tested and it must match the entire string.

Comment: Yes, it will display that row use like '%,6,%'

Comment: @TonyDong Thank you tony for your answer it helped me get it working!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using compat level 130, `string_split` will work:

```
where '6' in (select value from string_split(Categories, ','))
```

Alternatively, if you can build the data with a leading `,` and a trailing `,`, you could use

```
where Categories like `%,6,%`
```

However, csv is not usually a good idea for querying like this. Normalized query would be better.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm using 2014 which does not include the string-split function if i'm correct?

Comment: @AlexP yes you are correct, string_split is 2016 (possibly SP-something)

Comment: yea :( i need to upgrade this is making me pull my hair out to get to this point.

Comment: @AlexP well, I wouldn't normally *recommend* it in this scenario - unless you know the data is trivially small. I *would* be ok with the other way around, though - i.e. `where table.Column in (select value from string_split(@parameter, ','))`

Comment: This should be a lot slower than doing a join as my example.